# Firebase authentication with backend in android

Tags: php, android, firebase

I plan to use Firebase for authentication and build chat for my Android app. But I have  custom backend for rest of the APIs.
Can we use both custom backend and firebase authentication at the same time ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure thing. You'll need to:

1. [Sign the user in with Firebase Authentication in your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start).
2. Pass the [user's ID token from the app to your server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients) over a secure connection.
3. [Decode and validate the ID token.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients)
4. Ensure the user is authorized for the action they're trying to take.

Comment: i am already authenticate using server API is their any way to connect this server with firebase instead connect the app with firebase

Comment: What do you want the server to do with Firebase?

Comment: Authenticate with server 
And use authentication token to login to firebase 
To be able to make chat with firebase without using the server.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, but if you want to mint custom tokens on your server that you then use to sign the user into Firebase, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens